# Rg.Plugin.PopupPage error with the call line

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, popupwindow

I installed the plugin on the 3 projects (PCL/Android/IOS)
I am using Xamarin.forms and
The line that calls the popup page shows this error message after the app started:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Platform is not created occurred

```
 [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MenuView : ContentPage
{
    List<Loja> lstLojas;
    IGeolocator locator;
    Loja lojaPerto;
    Localizacao localizacao;
    MyPopupPage s;
    public MenuView()
    {
        s = new MyPopupPage();
        InitializeComponent();
        CallingGeolocatorAsync();
        login();
    }

    void login()
    {
        Navigation.PushPopupAsync(s, true);
    }
```

this is my PopUp Page.cs

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace neoFly_Montana.PopUp
{
public partial class MyPopupPage : PopupPage
{
    public MyPopupPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopupNavigation.PopAsync();
    }

    protected override Task OnAppearingAnimationEnd()
    {
        return Content.FadeTo(0.5);
    }

    protected override Task OnDisappearingAnimationBegin()
    {
        return Content.FadeTo(1);
    }
  }
}
```

this is my popup xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
         xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
         x:Class="neoFly_Montana.PopUp.MyPopupPage">
<!--Animations use example-->
<pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <animations:ScaleAnimation 
  PositionIn="Center"
  PositionOut="Center"
  ScaleIn="1.2"
  ScaleOut="0.8"
  DurationIn="400"
  DurationOut="300"
  EasingIn="SinOut"
  EasingOut="SinIn"
  HasBackgroundAnimation="True"/>
</pages:PopupPage.Animation>
<!-- Content -->
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call that in a contructor...you need to use:

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
            base.OnAppearing();

            s = new MyPopupPage();
            PopupNavigation.PushAsync(s, true);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Popuplogin.xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pages:PopupPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="SeralizationApp.Views.Popuplogin"
    xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    xmlns:myAnimations="clr-namespace:StalizationApp.Animations;assembly=MyProject">

    <StackLayout Margin="12"
                 Padding="24"
                 Spacing="24"
                 BackgroundColor="White"
                 HorizontalOptions="Center"
                 VerticalOptions="Center">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Login" />
            <Entry FontSize="30"
                   Text="Email" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Contraseña"/>
            <Entry FontSize="30"
                   IsPassword="True"
                   Text="Contraseña" />
        </StackLayout>
        //enter code here
        <Button BackgroundColor="DodgerBlue"
                FontSize="30"
                Text="Login"
                TextColor="White" />
    </StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

**Popuplogin.cs**

```
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace SeralizationApp.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Popuplogin : PopupPage // ContentView
    {
        public Popuplogin ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your solution? Either with additional comments or a synopsis.